# Powershell Console output not available

Tags: vba, powershell

I am trying to run a pwershell script from excel, which i can do and it works, but the powershell window does not show the information from the write-host comands in the script.  If i run the file from the cmd prompt i get all the write-host texts appearing in the console window, like below.

Powershell run from command prompt
[[image]]

However if i use this code from excel.

```
Sub RunAndGetCmd()

    strCommand = "Powershell -File ""C:\PSFiles\TestOutput.ps1"""
    Set WshShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
    Set WshShellExec = WshShell.Exec(strCommand)

End Sub
```

I get no texts shown in the console window, just the a flashing cursor like the following

Same Powershell ran from excel
[image]

I know the script runs and dooes everything, but i would like to output the texts as the script runs so i can see how far it has gotten.

Any ideas greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `WScript.Shell` [Exec](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions//ateytk4a(v=vs.85)) command redirects the stdin, stdout and stderr streams so you can access them from your application. As a result, anything written to stdout by the external application (e.g. using `write-host` in PowerShell) gets redirected instead of being displayed in the external application's window.

If you want the output displayed in the application's window you can use the [Run](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions//d5fk67ky(v=vs.85)) method instead - e.g.

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub RunAndGetCmd()

    Dim strCommand As String
    Dim WshShell As Object

    strCommand = "Powershell -File ""C:\PSFiles\TestOutput.ps1"""

    Set WshShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
    WshShell.Run strCommand

End Sub
```

but if you're doing that, you might as well just use the built-in VBA [Shell](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/shell-function) function:

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub RunAndGetCmd()

    Dim strCommand As String

    strCommand = "Powershell -File ""C:\PSFiles\TestOutput.ps1"""

    VBA.Shell strCommand

End Sub
```

Note also that you might want an `-ExecutionPolicy RemoteSigned` in your command in case the machine has it set to Restricted:

```
strCommand = "Powershell -ExecutionPolicy RemoteSigned -File ""C:\PSFiles\TestOutput.ps1"""
```

Comment: Thanks for the answers, i used the first suggestion as when i tried the second, i got issues with virus protection saying i was trying to run malicous macros. Very much appreciated.  While onthis, do you know if there is a way of staying in the code until the Powershell script has finished executing ?

Comment: @BrendanMcDonnell - the  documentation for the ```Run``` method describes an optional ```bWaitOnReturn``` parameter which might do what you're asking for...